# Is it possible to write ruby callbacks outside the model file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback

I am new to ruby on rails. I am wondering if there is any option to write ruby callbacks  outside the model file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ruby callbacks outside the model?, can you describe more?

Comment: normally the callbacks(before_save,after_save,..) are return inside the model files. i am asking is there any options for writing these outside model file.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: You can write them in a module, and then include the module into the model (or models) that you want.  This is useful if you have shared behaviour, to avoid repeated code.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using ActiveSupport::Concern

> create a file under app/model/concerns/model_callbacks.rb

```
 module ModelCallbacks
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      before_create :do_this
      #...
      def do_this
        # ...
      end
    end
 end
```

In model.rb include that concern

```
include ModelCallbacks
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be called from outside of the model and violate the principle of object encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

You can do by calling `require 'filename'` and placing the `filename` file on the `lib` folder. Also, as mentioned, you can use concerns.

**Example:**

```
#app/model/user.rb
require 'user_external_callbacks.rb'

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your normal class
end
```

---

```
#lib/user_external_callbacks.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :my_callback

  private

  def my_callback
  end
end
```

***PS:*** you don't need to call this `require` necessarily at the model file. You can put this `require` in any model file - at the beggining or at the end of the file, or at any initialization file ("config/initializers"), or application.rb, or practically any file that are called once by Rails

***PS II:*** unless its necessary, avoid to put your model callbacks in another file. You will get away from the default pattern of Rails coding and will be more difficult to others programmers maintain your code.